# Trouble rendering thymeleaf with springboot

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Hello everyone i am trying to run a simple springboot application. And trying to view a basic html but have trouble rendering the page. I can only see the string on browser but not the actual html contents. Please tell me what i did wrong.

TestController.java:

```
@Controller
public class TestController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/person")
    @ResponseBody
    public String intro(){
        System.out.println("HH");
        return "index";
    }
}
```

MainApplication.java:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "pathToMyControllerFolder")
public class MainApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

            SpringApplication.run(MainApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

created index.html in /rsesources/template folder as was mentioned on spring doc:
index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head lang="en">

    <title>Spring Framework Guru</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello</h1>

<h2>Fellow Spring Framework Gurus!!!</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

But i cannot vies the html contents but rather the string index. Earlier had whitePage label error and fixed it by adding the @ComponentScan but now only displaying index and not actual html contents.

And when i checked the log info on the console i noticed this:

```
2015-11-15 13:22:51.442  INFO 11460 --- [lication.main()] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2015-11-15 13:22:51.442  INFO 11460 --- [lication.main()] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `@ResponseBody` annotation. With that annotation whatever you return from the controller is the response body. In your case you return the `index` string, so that's the whole response body. Removing the annotation will cause the `index` string to be interpreted as a view name.

Comment: thanks so much. That worked.. So if intend to pass a variable to my view and get it rendered using html, i shouldn't annotate with @ResponseBody but with model and return the view that needs to be rendered right?

Comment: @EmyItegbe Right. You can add Model as a controller method's attribute, and put some stuff in it. Then just return the view name, as String:
    public String intro(Model model){
        model.addAtribute("attributeName", "attributeValue");
        return "index";
    }